# Footnote Issue in Overleaf

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, overleaf

I am facing a problem dealing with references to the same footnote text using the Overleaf online TeX/LaTeX system. Here is a minimum working example which compiles perfectly using MikTeX/TeXLive, but raises an error under Overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
I would like to use footnote here\footnote{\label{MyFootNoteLabel}} and there\footnotemark[\ref{MyFootNoteLabel}].
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.4 ...d there\footnotemark[\ref{MyFootNoteLabel}]
```

Would appreciate your feedback in this issue.

Comment: I would check the output of a local compile again; I can reproduce the error. In this scenario, it would be best to just have `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`. (Just because the compile finished doesn't mean the compile was successful.)

Comment: The local output was actually fine. This keeps something to be desired about such this Overleaf-only error. Thank you, your suggestions solved the issue.

Comment: Glad I could help :) but are you sure the local output was fine? Note that I'm not talking about the PDF output; I'm talking about the console output when you compile the document. Most editors configure TeX to continue running past errors (up to a certain threshold).

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact, compiling locally for the first time issues an error and three warnings, but after recompiling the PDF is produced with no errors.

Answer (score 5):

The `\label`-`\ref` mechanism requires two runs (the first time, or whenever the `.aux` file doesn't yet contain a reference to the label) in order that `\ref{MyFootNoteLabel}` generates a number. So the first time you compile the document there's an error, because the optional argument to `\footnotemark` requires a number.

Solution: use `refcount` and `\getrefnumber` instead of `\ref`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\textheight=3cm % just to keep the output small

\begin{document}

I would like to use footnote here\footnote{Some text for the footnote\label{MyFootNoteLabel}}
and there\footnotemark[\getrefnumber{MyFootNoteLabel}].

\end{document}
```

[image]